# Nombre más largo y nombre en mayúscula y minúscula

Tags: java

Estoy comenzando en programación y debo de agregar un código de `java` la siguiente instrucción:

Mostrar el nombre mas largo de una persona que haya ingresado el nombre y mostrarlo en mayúscula y minúscula de la persona mas joven, les dejo el código que tengo:

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import java.lang.*;//hay estan todas las clases 
public  class ejercicio
{
public static void main(String args[])
{

    int n,cont,edad,dv;
    String nom;
    n=Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("cuantos datos desea ingresar"));
    for(cont=0;cont<n;cont++)
    {

        nom=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("ingrese nombre");
        edad=Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("ingrese la edad"));
        dv=edad*365;
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,nom + " usted ha vivido " + dv + "dias" + "su nombre tiene " + nom.length() + "letras" );
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"su nombre en mayuscula es " + nom.toUpperCase());
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"la primera letra de su nombre es" + nom.charAt(0));
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"la raiz cuadrada de la edad es " + (float)Math.sqrt(edad));
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"la raiz cubica de la edad es " + (float)Math.cbrt(edad));
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"el cubo de su edad es " + Math.pow(edad,3));

    }
  }
}
```

Comment: **'Mostrar el nombre más largo (en mayúscula y minúscula de la persona más joven)'** No comprendo bien, ¿quieres que para una persona (la más joven) existan n cantidad de nombres y de esos mostrar el más largo? ¿O lo que buscas es que de n personas, se elija la que tiene el nombre más largo y se muestre?

Answer (score 1):

Vale, entiendo que debes de devolver el nombre en mayúsculas con el nombre mas largo y el nombre en minúscula del nombre con menor edad.

Teniendo en cuenta que esto sea lo deseado, debes de conservar los nombres que cumplen las condiciones.

```
public static void main(String args[])
{

int n,cont,edad,dv;
String nom;
//Añadimos tres variables nuevas
String longestName="";
String youngestName="";
int youngestAge=10000;

n=Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("cuantos datos desea ingresar"));
for(cont=0;cont<n;cont++)
{

    nom=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("ingrese nombre");
    edad=Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("ingrese la edad"));

    //Cuando insertamos un nuevo nombre y edad, checkeamos si cumple alguna de las dos condiciones
    if(nom.length()>longestName.length()){
        longestName=nom.toUpperCase();
    }
    if(edad<youngestAge){
        youngestName=nom.toLowerCase();
    }        


    dv=edad*365;
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,nom + " usted ha vivido " + dv + "dias" + "su nombre tiene " + nom.length() + "letras" );
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"su nombre en mayuscula es " + nom.toUpperCase());
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"la primera letra de su nombre es" + nom.charAt(0));
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"la raiz cuadrada de la edad es " + (float)Math.sqrt(edad));
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"la raiz cubica de la edad es " + (float)Math.cbrt(edad));
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"el cubo de su edad es " + Math.pow(edad,3));

}

JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"El nombre mas largo " +longestName);
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"El nombre del mas joven " +youngestName);
}
```